How do I make the input type radio so that it can be checked?
I have the problem that when I insert the check to the first one and then I insert another one and the check is passed to the new one that is entered and the idea is that it stays there in the first one that I entered.
method
private async Task GuardarModalDireccion()
{
    if (isEditDireccion)
    {
        dataDireccionGrid[dataDireccionForm.INDEX] = dataDireccionForm;
    }
    else
    {
        var splitDireccion = dataDireccionForm.CIUDANEID.Split("-");
        if (splitDireccion.Length >= 3)
        {
            Direcciones direcciones = new Direcciones
            {
                CIUDANEID = splitDireccion[0].Trim(),
                DIRECCION = $"{dataDireccionForm.DIRECCION}, {splitDireccion[1].Trim()}, {splitDireccion[2].Trim()}"
            };
            if(dataDireccionGrid.Count > 0){
                direcciones.ESTADO = 0;
            }
            dataDireccionGrid.Add(direcciones);
        }
    }

    await modalDireccion.HideAsync();

    dataDireccionForm = new Direcciones();

    StateHasChanged();
}

blazor
 <Tab Title="Direcciones">
     <Content>
         <div class="d-flex flex-column w-100">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-custom mt-3" id="btnInsertarDireccion" style="width: max-content" @onclick="showModalInsertarDireccion">
                 <i class="bi bi-plus-lg"></i> Insertar
             </button>
             <div class="row w-100 mt-3 m-0">
                 <div class="col-12 px-0">
                     @if (dataDireccionGrid?.Count > 0)
                     {
                         <div class="list-group gap-2">
                             @for (int i = 0; i < dataDireccionGrid.Count; i++)
                             {
                                 var item = dataDireccionGrid[i];
                                 item.INDEX = i;
                                 <div class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                     <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
                                         <input type="radio" name="direccion" class="d-flex flex-row gap-1" value="@item.DIRECID" id="direccion-@i" checked="@(item.ESTADO == 1 ? "true" : "false")" />
                                         <label for="direccion-@i" class="ml-2">
                                             @item.DIRECCION
                                         </label>
                                     </div>
                                     
                                     <div>
                                         <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary rounded my-1" @onclick="(e) => {showModalEditDireccion(item);}"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square "></i></button>
                                     <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary rounded" @onclick="(e) => {dataDireccionGrid.Remove(item);}"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i></button>

                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                             }
                         </div>
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         <p>No se han encontrado Direcciones.</p>
                     }
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </Content>
 </Tab>

help me there in the coding of the check I work with a status 1 and 0 but I have this little problem that every time I enter one it always puts the check on the one that is entered new.
help with this problem please

Your description is hard to understand.
As my understanding, you clicked to check first item, clicked to check second item, then first item got unchecked. You want the first item remain checked, when you click to check second item. Is it currect?

If it is, you should not use radio buttons. The radio buttons is to provide mutually exclusive options. Use checkbox instead.

<input type="radio"/> buttons with the same name are like <select><option /></select>, in that you are picking a single value, but the individual values are spread around the page.

Do you want to keep only one option selected (Previous selection) after inserting the new address? Or do you want both the new address and the previously selected option to remain selected?
